# Accessing previous value in Hashtable during page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview, hashtable

I have a hyperlink field in a gridview. I want to store all the clicked value during a session in a hashtable for that hyperlink field.

```
protected partial class User : System.Web.UI.Page
{
        Hashtable htable = new Hashtable();
        int hTableIndex = 0;
        // ...
}
```

In Page Load Function.

```
if(Session["test"] != null)`
{   
     for(int i = 0 ; i gvUserStatus.Rows.Count ; i++)
     Hashtable tempHashTable = new Hashtable();
     tempHashTable = Session["test"] as Hashtable;
     if(tempHashTable.Contains(someValue)) 
     {
          //Do Something
     }
}
```

In link click event:

```
protected void userID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //logic to get the ClickedValue
    if(!htable.Contains(ClickedValue))
    {
        htable.Add(hTableIndex++,ClickedValue);
    }
    Session["test"] = htable;
}
```

I am using the above code, but in my hash table, only the last clicked value is getting stored, what should I do to get all the previous value for an entire user session?

Answer (score 1):

`hTableIndex` will lose its value upon `postback`. You will need to store it in `Session` as well (or just `ViewState` if you won't need it's value on other pages)

So you need to add this in your `Page_Load` event:

```
if (ViewState["hTableIndex"] == null)
    ViewState["hTableIndex"] = hTableIndex;
```

and in your link click event `userID_Click`

```
protected void userID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //logic to get the ClickedValue
    if(!htable.Contains(ClickedValue))
    {
        var hTableIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["hTableIndex"]);
        htable.Add(hTableIndex++,ClickedValue);
    }
    Session["test"] = htable;
}
```

Let me know if this works. Haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within your hTableIndex which will always point to 0 on reloading the page, you also need to put it in the session, so that next time you can get the max value of hTableIndex and add the new link at that index